# NSManagedObject initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobject

I have a Core Data store set up with an Xcode-generated subclass of NSManagedObject: Note.

I can use NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName: inManagedObjectContext: with no trouble, but when I try to do this:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [(QuickTextAppDelegate*)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) managedObjectContext];

    Note* note = [[Note alloc] initWithEntity:@"Note" insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Using breakpoints I can see that the NSManagedObjectContext* in indeed pointing to a valid object.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14):

I see at least one problem there: `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` takes an NSEntityDescription, not an NSString. Try something like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
Note* note = [[Note alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sure I had consulted the documentation and tried everything, but apparently I was not paying enough attention to what an NSEntityDescription was!